# Example in the 'rasterize' documentation does not work?

Tags: r, r-raster

I use the `rasterize` function from the `raster` package quite often. As indicated in its documentation, any custom function being used through the `fun` argument needs to accept an `na.rm` argument. This generally means that custom functions are written with the 'dots', i.e.:

```
funA <- function(x,...)length(x)
```

However, a second proposed approach is to write a custom function with an explicit `na.rm` argument. The example that is given in the documentation is:

```
funB <- function(x, na.rm) if (na.rm) length(na.omit(x))
```

However, this does not seem to work! This example, in which some random points are distributed across a grid fails:

```
# Create a grid
grid <- raster(ncols=36, nrows=18)

# Scatter some random points within the grid
pts <- spsample(as(extent(grid), "SpatialPolygons"), 100, type = "random")

# Give them a random data field
pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data.frame(field1 = runif(length(pts))))

# Try rasterize
rasterize(pts, grid, field = "field1", fun = funB)
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You were close.

Function B should look like:

```
funB <- function(x, na.rm=T) if (na.rm) length(na.omit(x))
rasterize(pts, grid, field = "field1", fun = funB)
```

the `na.rm` argument as to be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, adding a default value deals with the problem.

What still annoys' me is that this:

```
funB <- function(x, na.rm) if (na.rm) length(na.omit(x))
rasterize(pts, grid, field = "field1", fun = funB, na.rm=TRUE)
```

should work but it doesn't.  It's maybe something with the raster package.

Comment: Aha. Well, that'll certainly work for my purposes. Many thanks